# Why django ORM .filter() two way binding my data?

Tags: python, python-3.x, django

Let's say I store my query result temporarily to a variable

```
temp_doc = Document.objects.filter(detail=res)
```

and then I want to insert some data in said model
and will be something like this

```
p = Document(detail=res)
p.save()
```

note that `res` are object from other model to make some FK relation.

For some reason the `temp_doc` will contain the new data.

Are .filter() supposed to work like that? 
Because with .get() the data inside `temp_doc` don't change

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Django Querysets are lazy, this behavior is well [documented](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/db/queries/#querysets-are-lazy)

> QuerySets are lazy – the act of creating a QuerySet doesn’t involve
> any database activity. You can stack filters together all day long,
> and Django won’t actually run the query until the QuerySet is
> evaluated.

So basically that means until you don't ask for data evaluation, database query won't be executed

---

In your example

```
temp_doc = Document.objects.filter(detail=res)
p = Document(detail=res)
p.save()
enter code here
```

evaluating temp_doc now would include newly created Document as database query would return it

---

simply constructing list would evaluate QuerySet at the start

```
#evaluation happens here
list(temp_doc) = Document.objects.filter(detail=res)

p = Document(detail=res)
p.save()
```